# I am using selenium webdriver 2.53.1 with java and firefox 45.0.1 and try to login with linktext(open popup window) with hidden class

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hme_lgfrm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login or Join Us</a>
```

and found error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 

Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Login or Join Us"}

Command duration or timeout: 4.82 seconds

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hme_lgfrm"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login or Join Us</a>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: What is your locator

Comment: is this help full...actually i am new on this so i dont know how to use it exactly

Comment: @iamsankalp89 it is linktext i guess which opens a popup window after click on it

Comment: @AnkurMishra try with xpath Please see th answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath

```
//a[@class='hme_lgfrm']
```

and use JavascriptExwcutor to click it try this code:

```
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver( );
JavascriptExecutor myExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='hme_lgfrm']"));
myExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Welcome Glad it help you